# How to union an array when grouping?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to combine multiple array columns into one with distinct elements and then get a count of distinct elements. How can I do something like that in postgres?

```
 create temp table t as ( select 'james' as fn, array ['bond', 'milner'] as ln );

 create temp table tt as ( select 'james' as fn, array ['mcface', 'milner'] as ln );
-- expected value: james, 3

    select x.name,
           array_length()-- what to do here?
    from (
             select fn, ln
             from t
             union
             select fn, ln
             from tt
         ) as x
    group by x.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unnest the arrays in the inner queries:

```sql
select x.fn,
       count(elem) 
from (
         select fn, unnest(ln) as elem
         from t
         union
         select fn, unnest(ln) as elem
         from tt
     ) as x
group by x.fn
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0d9f10592cd7df4a49d73fbb00ca4541)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you (want to) use arrays? That's not needed. Simply have a derived table using `UNION`, which eliminates duplicates, `GROUP BY` the `name` and use `count()`.

```
SELECT name,
       count(*)
       FROM (SELECT name,
                    ln
                    FROM t
             UNION
             SELECT name,
                    ln
                    FROM tt) AS x
       GROUP BY name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=82e48624fc13ce07ad98f673dc0b2639)

Side note: 9.3 is out of support for a while. Consider upgrading.

Comment: that part I cant control. i am already querying a data that is in such shape. i should have clarified that in my question. updating...

Comment: Just for future reference, this answer would have been a solution to the way I set up my example initially in my question. I updated my mvp code to reflect my scenario more accurately.